# HighchartsReact render the graph when minimize or maximize the browser

Tags: css, highcharts, react-highcharts

How can I render the graph when minimize or maximize the browser?
I don't know if it's related to the graph config or to the style.

just to make it clear.
this is how to graph looks like when the page is in it max:
[image]

this is how the graph liks like when I'm minimize the browser:
[image]

I'm "loosing" the indication of the last day.

when I'm refreshing the page while the browser is still minimized, it is fixed.

this is the current styling config:

```
containerProps={{style: {height: "335px",width:"100%"}}}
```

Any chance someone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Hi @Tal Levi, I haven't encountered such behaviour. Could you reproduce the issue in some online code editor? You can use this simple example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-gbg3n3 as a base to start.

Answer (score 0):

in the end, I just added an event, that when ever the page is resized, the page will be render.

used this artical:
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/re-render-react-component-on-window-resize